# MapFallbackToPage on subfolder in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to create a fallback route to a Razor page inside my ASP.NET Core application so I can host a server-side Blazor app on a subpath. Creating a fallback route from the root works as described in the documentation. But I want it my fallback on routes `/Admin/*`.

My current code looks like this:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // ...
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/Admin", "/Admin/_Host");
});
```

I've also tried to use the following setup:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // ...
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/Admin/{*segment}", "/Admin/_Host");
});
```

Both configurations end up generating a 404 when I enter a URL for a page that exists in my Blazor app.
I verified that navigating **within** the Blazor app using `<NavLink>` does work.

What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: Please insert: what comes in the `endpoints.MapFallbackToPage`; the url you're trying to hit; the `@page` of your component

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out that I should have used the following piece of code:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    // ...
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/Admin/{**segment}", "/Admin/_Host");
});
```

Note the `**` in the pattern. It's a recursive mapping for all segments in the URL that come after the `/Admin` part. I was only using a single star, which caused the deeply nested URLs to not match the pattern.

I learned that the pattern for the `MapFallbackToPage` method accepts a regular routing pattern.

For those interested in learning more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0

### Alternative solution

You can also add a `@page "/Admin/{**segment}"` directive at the top of `_Host.cshtml`. You'll have to remove the `MapFallbackToPage` call in `Startup.cs`.