# CSS Not Working In _Host.chstml In Blazor Server

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core, blazor

Here I have blazor server app, in app I have two _Host.cshtml, one for website which is default `_Host.cshtml` and another for admin panel that is `_HostAdmin.cshtml`. Both of them have separate css and js file. I too have separate layout, for website I have `Mainlayout.razor` which should use `_Host.cshtml` and for admin panel I have `AdminLayout.razor` which should use `_HostAdmin.cshtml` .
Now, the problem is that when I add new razor component and use `AdminLayout.razor` layout the view doesnot use css and js of  `_HostAdmin.cshtml`.

Below is my _HostAdmin.cshtml

```
@page "/Admin"
@namespace MCQ.Pages._Pages_Admin__HostAdmin
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <title>Admin Dashboard</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

     <base href="~/Admin" />

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Adminlte/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Adminlte/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Adminlte/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/css/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Adminlte/plugins/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Adminlte/plugins/jqvmap/jqvmap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Adminlte/dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Adminlte/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Adminlte/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Adminlte/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
  <body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini layout-fixed">

    <div class="wrapper">
       <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
    </div>

    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script>$.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button)</script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/sparklines/sparkline.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/jqvmap/jquery.vmap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/jqvmap/maps/jquery.vmap.usa.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/jquery-knob/jquery.knob.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/moment/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4/js/tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/summernote/summernote-bs4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/dist/js/adminlte.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Adminlte/dist/js/demo.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Below is Startup.cs

```
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("~/Admin/{*clientroutes:nonfile}", "/_HostAdmin");
        });
```

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65494101/60761

Comment: @HenkHolterman : I changed my endpoint to `endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/Admin/{**segment}", "/Admin/_HostAdmin"); ` but it did not work

Comment: VS doesn't automatically run As Admin.  If running in VS right click VS shortcut and select Run As Adim.   The application will also run by just running the executable from outside VS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state

> Now, the problem is that when I add new razor component and use AdminLayout.razor layout the view doesnot use css and js of _HostAdmin.cshtml.

and I assume your question is "Why".

You're adding a new razor component page to the existing application - probably with a route of something like "/admin/myadminpage". You're misunderstanding what's actually going on.

*_Host.cshtml* loads the SPA, but that's the only get/post that happens.  Navigation after that is changing out components in the DOM.  Loading a component with the layout `AdminLayout` just changes out the Layout component.  There's no toing and froing with the server.

What you are trying to do requires a reload of the SPA.  You could use:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/admin/myadminpage", true);
```

Also even if you do force a reload, the Fallbacks are in the wrong order - the default before the specific.

```
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("~/Admin/{*clientroutes:nonfile}", "/_HostAdmin");
```

Comment: thank you, it worked what is the correct order of fallback